# iOS Unknown class OXMAdBanner in Interface Builder file. 64-bit architecture

Tags: ios, exception, interface-builder, ads

I have next problem. I have implement advertisement to my application using next SDK http://docs.openx.com/sdk/
http://openx.com/product/mobile-ad-serving-for-app-developers/
And everything work perfect until I try to launch my application at new iPhone 5S. Only on  this type of devices I am receive next error:

```
  Unknown class OXMAdBanner in Interface Builder file.
    [UIView setDomain:portraitAdUnitID:landscapeAdUnitID:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UIView setDomain:portraitAdUnitID:landscapeAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10fea5630'
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with Architectures to solve my issue I have change Standard architectures including 64-bit to Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)